# How to Auto Validate the Answers in Android game application using nlp library?

Tags: android, nlp

I am developing an android game application in that after player finished questions how to auto validate the answers?

Comment: Start by reading [how to ask aquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually i asked in an game application after player finished all questions how to validate all answers automatically.